# cURL with PHP question for logging in to https:// remote site

Tags: php, url, curl

So I have this cURL script for remote login. It works fine for some pages but not the pages I need.

For the page that isn't accessible through the script, the remote server requires the url be like this:

```
  https://sub.example.com/a/b/thisPage.aspx?aVar=%2Fa%2Fb%2Fc%2Fd%2FFile+Name.nev
```

It seems that cURL or just php automatically converts the last part to

```
  ... thisPage.aspx?aVar=/a/b/c/d/File+Name.nev
```

I have php echo out the url variable just before it is passed to cURL and the last part is:

```
  ...thisPage.aspx?aVar=%2Fa%2Fb%2Fc%2Fd%2FFile+Name.nev
```

but it gives an error
message "Bad Request" and the browser url shows:

```
  ...thisPage.aspx?aVar=/a/b/c/d/File+Name.nev
```

When I manually enter enter ... thisPage.aspx?aVar=%2Fa%2Fb%2Fc%2Fd%2FFile+Name.nev in my browser it pulls up the page just fine.

Comment: You might want to post the script.

Answer (score 2):

Try double encoding so that way the % are encoded to. Try replacing them with `%25`.